# Screen a running process

Tags: linux, shell, process, migration, gnu-screen

Sometimes I forget to run a program under a screen session and can't stop it in the middle, and I know it's going to take long.

Is there a way to screen an already running process without restarting it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a duplicate In [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process).

Another solution not found in that post is using [retty](http://pasky.or.cz/~pasky/dev/retty/) after starting a screen session.

Comment: I deleted my answer; you can (and should) accept your own answer after 2 days. Feel free to quote the relevant parts here, as cross-site "duplicates" really aren't dupes due to the different audiences.

Comment: But you didn't quote the relevant parts, as per Jeff's suggestion. =)

Answer (score 12):

Found this answer on serverfault from [earl](https://serverfault.com/questions/55880/moving-an-already-running-process-to-screen/55881#55881):

> However, for your actual problem, there's another thing you could try: after having launched your job from the terminal, background it by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> and then `bg`.
>   After that, detach the job from it's parent shell - in `bash`: `disown -h %<jobid>`. After that, you can safely close the terminal and the job will continue running.

And this one from the same question from [Rob Wells](https://serverfault.com/questions/55880/moving-an-already-running-process-to-screen/55882#55882):

> `$ screen -S my_process`
>      `$ retty $(pgrep my_process)`
>      `/redraw`

Comment: Is there any way to get the job to foreground again? 'screen' then 'fg 1' doesn't work for me

Comment: @Putnik - did you do the other steps as described?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr), which does exactly that.  The github page has all the information.

> reptyr - A tool for "re-ptying"
>
> ### programs.
>
> reptyr is a utility for taking an
>   existing running program and attaching
>   it to a new terminal. Started a
>   long-running process over ssh, but
>   have to leave and don't want to
>   interrupt it? Just start a screen, use
>   reptyr to grab it, and then kill the
>   ssh session and head on home.
>
> ### USAGE
>
> reptyr PID
>
> "reptyr PID" will grab the process
>   with id PID and attach it to your
>   current terminal.
>
> After attaching, the process will take
>   input from and write output to the new
>   terminal, including ^C and ^Z.
>   (Unfortunately, if you background it,
>   you will still have to run "bg" or
>   "fg" in the old terminal. This is
>   likely impossible to fix in a
>   reasonable way without patching your
>   shell.)