# Moving a process from a shell to another?

Tags: unix, shell, gnu-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screen a running process](https://superuser.com/questions/28568/screen-a-running-process)

Is it possible to move a process from one shell to another? Ex: I have launched a process in some shell, and I decide I'd like to move it to my GNU screen session. Is that possible?

Comment: See this: http://superuser.com/questions/28568/screen-a-running-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot reparent a process except by killing its parent, at which point it becomes a child of `init`.

Comment: Is there any reason for that?

Comment: It just isn't a supported operation in POSIX.